# what is mainLoop in Java?

Tags: java

I labor under the delusion that this is a simple question which should have a simple answer. I say that because a simple google search of "what is mainLoop in Java" returns no such answer. I'm just looking for a Java 101 level answer to this question. The context in which I have encountered this is in this line of code:

```
mainLoop: for(StackTraceElement ste: Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(){
    //stuff here
}
```

What is mainLoop in Java?

Comment: it's lable .important when you want a break or continue

Comment: Thank you. So I should have been searching for what is a Label instead of what is mainLoop. That's what I needed to know.  Considering I've only been using Java for like a couple months there's still a bunch I don't know. If you want to phrase that as an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7